# find by TagName inside Node of XML file

Tags: java, xml, dom, xml-parsing

I'm using *Dom Parser* in *Java* to process a *XML* file. Is I have an Object of type **Node**,how can I find elements by name inside that Node? I know how to find by tag name from all the document, I have this:

```
dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(this.file);
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("SomeTag");
```

But then, inside every item of `nList` how I find by tagName?should I have to loop on it and make comparations?

**EDITED:**

The structure of the XML tree is as follows, there's a lot of *agents*:

```
</agent>
    <agent name='agente2' id='ug4pht1ju6ru8u5aot37tcb5po'>
        <AgentModel>
            <Posicion></Posicion>
            <MarcoReferencia></MarcoReferencia>
            <AgenteDescripcion></AgenteDescripcion>
            <Componentes>
            </Componentes>
            <Objetivo>
                <Nombre></Nombre>
                <Descripcion></Descripcion>
                <Activacion></Activacion>
                <Finalizacion></Finalizacion>
                <Exito></Exito>
                <Fracaso></Fracaso>
                <Ontologia></Ontologia>
                <Entradas>
                </Entradas>
                <Salidas>
                </Salidas>
            </Objetivo>
            <Servicios>
            </Servicios>
            <Propiedades>
                <Nombre></Nombre>
                <Calidad></Calidad>
                <Auditable></Auditable>
                <Garantia></Garantia>
                <Capacidad></Capacidad>
                <Confiabilidad></Confiabilidad>
            </Propiedades>
            <Capacidad>
                <Habilidades></Habilidades>
                <Representacion></Representacion>
                <Lenguaje></Lenguaje>
            </Capacidad>
            <Restriccion>
                <Normas></Normas>
                <Preferencias></Preferencias>
                <Permisos></Permisos>
            </Restriccion>

        </AgentModel>
        <CommunicationModel>
        </CommunicationModel>
        <CoordinationModel>
        </CoordinationModel>
    <MarcoOntologicoIndividual>
    </MarcoOntologicoIndividual>
    <Asociaciones>
</Asociaciones>
    <Actores>
</Actores>
    <CasosUso>
</CasosUso>

    </agent>
```

So, in a NodeList a have all the agents, then, for each of them I want get the tags looking by name

Comment: Can you provide an example of the structure of the XML you are trying to parse and highlight the elements you are trying to find?

Comment: @MadProgrammer sure, I edited

Comment: Assuming you know the names of the nodes you want to find, you can use an xpath query, maybe `AgentModel/Objetivo/Nombre` from the current `agent` node, or `/agent[@name='agente2']/AgentModel/Objetivo/Nombre` if you want to search the document for a particularly named agent (and then get the `Nombre` node)

Comment: @MadProgrammer thank you man!! that's awesome!